# ElasticSearch query not returning expected results

Tags: elasticsearch

The following query and index do not return the expected results. I don't understand, given the mapping constraint, when I search for "ICD9" it also returns results for "I9" and "9" among others. Any ideas?

```
Here is the index mapping:
{
  "mappings": {
    "mymap": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
           "codingstandard": {
              "match": "*.CodingStandard",
              "mapping": {
                 "type": "string",
                 "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
           }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Here is my query:
{
  "fields": [
    "Diagnosis.CodingStandard"
  ],
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Diagnosis.CodingStandard:ICD9"
    }
  }
}

Here are some of my results:
"hits": {
  "total": 9778,
  "max_score": 3.501487,
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mymapping",
        "_id": "264235",
        "_score": 3.501487,
        "fields": {
           "Diagnosis.CodingStandard": [
              "I9"
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mymapping",
        "_id": "264261",
        "_score": 3.501487,
        "fields": {
           "Diagnosis.CodingStandard": [
              "9"
           ]
        }
     },
etc...
```

Comment: can you check the mapping of the field `GET your_index/_mapping/field/Diagnosis.CodingStandard` ?

Comment: {
   "myindex": {
      "mappings": {
         "mymapping": {
            "Diagnosis.CodingStandard": {
               "full_name": "Diagnosis.CodingStandard",
               "mapping": {
                  "Diagnosis.CodingStandard": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

Comment: I did the exact same thing and It is working for me, I get only _ICD9_ back, what version of ES you are using?

Comment: ElasticSearch v1.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Yes because you are using query_string, elasticsearch doing fuzzy search by default for query_string.

if you want to do exact search you can do filter instead of query_string

```
{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
          "filter":{
             "term":{
                "Diagnosis.CodingStandard": "ICD9"
             }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Same result.        {
            "_index": "myindex",
            "_type": "mymapping",
            "_id": "264200",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
               "Diagnosis.CodingStandard": [
                  "I9"
               ]
            }
         },

Comment: try this{
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
          "filter":{
             "term":{
                "Diagnosis.CodingStandard": "Icd9"
             }
          }
      }
   }
}

Comment: Try with all lower case of your string in term does not work ?

Comment: OK I think what you need is delete the index re create it then try the query.

Comment: Can you me the mapping and the setting of index?

Comment: The mapping is the original statement, no index settings. I did recreate the index, no change.